# Limit the size of each log file and set max history

Tags: 2011

I have been trying to put a limit over the size of each log file and even cleaning up if it is older than some specified period as below (I have pasted a small piece).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true">
    <!-- Properties -->
    <property name="log.pattern" value="%date %-5level %logger{0} - %message%n"/>
    <property name="log.history" value="7"/>
    <property name="log.folder" value="D:/Tridion/logs/httpupload"/>
    <property name="log.level" value="DEBUG"/>

    <!-- Appenders -->
    <appender name="rollingTransportLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/cd_transport.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>${log.history}</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <prudent>true</prudent>
    </appender>
    <appender name="rollingDeployerLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/cd_deployer.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>${log.history}</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <prudent>true</prudent>
    </appender>
</configuration>
```

Nothing is happening and most importantly cleaning should happen as logs folder is eating huge space on server. Am i doing it in right way?

Comment: This has already been asked and answered here: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/253/logback-xml-limit-the-size-of-files/260

Comment: It doesn't provide an answer for max history

Comment: Raúl's answer has both file size and max number of files in it.

Comment: Perhaps irrelevant... but you may want to reconsider using "DEBUG" level, as that indeed will use a lot of disk space (you may have a solid reason to do this, hence my "perhaps irrelevant" comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add %i in the file name pattern as below.

${log.folder}/cd_deployer.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log

We have configured FixedWindowRollingPolicy as below which is working and keeps only 5 files and of max size limit as 50MB.

```
<appender name="rollingTransportLog" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${log.folder}/cd_transport.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${log.folder}/cd_transport.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>5</maxIndex>
            </rollingPolicy>
            <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
      <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
         <encoder>
            <pattern>${log.pattern}</pattern>
        </encoder>
<prudent>false</prudent>
    </appender>
```

More details about Logback appenders can be found [here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html).
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

There are some known issues with Logback which SDL Tridion is using behind the scene for logging. Also, there may be some scenarios where your log history might not get deleted.

You may want to refer below links for further details and scenarios to understand it:

[LOGBACK-162](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-162?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3achangehistory-tabpanel)

[LBCORE-147_1](http://marc.info/?l=logback-dev&m=130081863812537)

[LBCORE-147_2](http://mailman.qos.ch/pipermail/logback-dev/2011-August/006454.html)